# Образование уменьшительной формы

Tags: словообразование

Скажите, пожалуйста, есть ли какая-то закономерность в образовании уменьшительной формы в таких похожих словах, как "кузнец", "огурец", "молодец", "конец"? Почему "кузнец-кузнечик", но "огурец-огурчик", а не "огуречек" и т.д.?
Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... есть ли какая-то
> закономерность в образовании
> уменьшительной формы в таких похожих
> словах, как "кузнец", "огурец", "молодец",
> "конец"? Почему "кузнец-кузнечик", но "огурец-
> огурчик", а не "огуречек"...

Много имеется нюансов)
Кузнец - человек, кузнечик - насекомое, слова практически не пересекаются в своем употреблении, только в детских стихах можно назвать кузнечика - кузнецом. То же самое относится к огурцу. *Огуречик* - персонаж сказок и мультфильмов, одушевленный литературный герой, а *огурчик* - маленький маринованный хрустящий огурец.
Молодец и молодчик являются разными по значению словами, второе - с явной отрицательной коннотацией. Интересное исключение, вроде как.
Можно сделать вывод. Если суффикс -ец просто заменяется уменьшительным суффиксом -чик (леден/ец - леден/чик), то начальное слово всего лишь получает прямое умалительное значение. Леденчик - маленький, особенно *вкуснючий* леденец. Кончик - миниатюрный конец чего-либо.

> Н.А. Полевой. Живописец (1833) Веринька перестала плакать, потупила глаза и щипала **кончик платка** своего.

Перец - перчик, огурец - огурчик, немец - немчик, итальянец - итальянчик, танец - танчик, заяц (зай/ец) - зайчик и др.

Если к суффиксу -ец присоединить уменьшительный суффикс -ик (плюс переход Ц-Ч в суффиксе -ец), то слово приобретает некий особенный детский шарм. Всего два таких слова в русском языке - кузнечик и огуречик!))) Сюда же добавим окказиональный *конечик* из детского же стиха и фамилию **Немечек**, которая звучит по-детски ласково (суффикс -ек нерусский, скорее польско-чешский).
Я надеюсь, угадал направление мысли автора вопроса (?)

Comment: Да, спасибо большое за развернутый ответ!

Answer (score 3):

Закономерность, конечно,есть. Вот у Виноградова, например :
http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?0a0=3&p=5310&s=0

А вот почему огурчик, а не огуречек/огуречик - это уже не определённое правило, а языковая/речевая практика, видимо. Так слово вошло в словари и стало литературной нормой - может, более благозвучно. А вторые варианты-разговорный окказионализм, знакомый нам по присказке "Огуречик, огуречик,
Не ходи на тот конечик –
Там мышка живет, 
Тебе хвостик отгрызет!" и песенке про кузнечика.
Об этом здесь:
    http://www.gramma.ru/RUS/?id=13.18

Comment: Мне тоже сразу об этой песенке подумалось))))